# events.js: 72 error - Erro rodar minha primeira app global com express

Tags: node.js

Fiz a instalação global do express no Ubuntu (e no meu Mac também) usando

```
npm install -g express
```

Depois, criei minha app usando o comando:

```
express -se hello_express
```

Entrei no diretório da aplicação e digitei:

```
npm install
```

Quando tento rodar no node usando o comando

```
node app.js
```

ele acusa o seguinte erro:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
  at listen (net.js:1061:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/caminho_da_aplicacao/hello_express/app.js:36:24)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Estou começando agora com "node + express", por isso gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso, se estou fazendo algo errado e como faço para resolver.

Comment: Você esqueceu de por justamente o código de sua app, que é o mais importante

Comment: O código está o padrão, criado automaticamente pelo express em app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

A porta que o express vai usar já está sendo usada, escolha outra: a porta é definida por essa linha `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);` no app.js, logo [mude a variável](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Assignment) `PORT`.

Como foi mostrado [nessa questão do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075287/1850091) você também vai encontrar esse erro quando você fechar sua app inesperadamente, que é sem a chance da aplicação liberar as portas. Caso esse seja seu caso lá há as respostas.

Comment: Foi exatamente este o problema. Alterei o valor da porta que por padrão é 3000 para 4000 e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Boa sacada. Vejo esse tipo de erro eventualmente e nem parei para ver o detalhe do EADDRINUSE. É essa resposta mesmo